# react-i18next: How do I interpolate an a tag with an icon into the description?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

In our codebase we are using react-i18next

```js
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const { t: i18n } = useTranslation();
```

And it is using texts from a file `src/locales/en/translation.json` to populate the content

in this file, we have

```
"settingsPage": {
  "customEndpoint": {
  "description": "Some sentences. {{SDKLinkText}}. Some senteces",
  "SDKLinkText": "SDKs",
  },
```

So here I want `SDKLinkText` to be a `<a />` like this

```html
<a href={url}>
    {i18n("settingsPage.customEndpoint.SDKLinkText")}
    <Icon variant="link" name="external" />
  </a>
```

So I did

```js
{
  i18n("settingsPage.customEndpoint.description", {
    SDKLinkText: <a href={url}>
    {i18n("settingsPage.customEndpoint.SDKLinkText")}
    <Icon variant="link" name="external" />
  </a>;
  });
}
```

But intead of rendering a `a` tag in the UI, it just prints out the string of the tag. I wonder what is the correct way to interpolate an HTML tag with `react-i18next`